AWS DMS Migration Task Fails with "No Tables Found" Using Wildcard in Schema Mapping for MySQL. Wildcard mapping rule is not working properly
I am working on migrating data from MySQL to S3 using AWS DMS. I want to employ wildcard mapping for the schema name in the DMS task's selection rules. Specifically, I aim to include tables from schema names starting with 'a', 'b', or 'c'. However, my attempts with [abc]% and [a-c]% have proven unsuccessful. Instead, I encountered an error stating 'AWS DMS Migration Task Fails with "No Tables Found" Using Wildcard in Schema Mapping' with all the methods I tried. Interestingly, it did work when I used 'a%' to capture all schemas starting with 'a'. Can someone please help me that what wildcard mapping use to get schema names starting with 'a', 'b', or 'c'.

You can create a wildcard against all tables in the selected schema(s). I bet this would work.
{
    "rules": [
        {
            "rule-type": "selection",
            "rule-id": "1",
            "rule-name": "include tables - schema a",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "a%",
                "table-name": "%"
            },
            "rule-action": "include",
            "filters": []
        },
        {
            "rule-type": "selection",
            "rule-id": "2",
            "rule-name": "include tables - schema b",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "b%",
                "table-name": "%"
            },
            "rule-action": "include",
            "filters": []
        },
        {
            "rule-type": "selection",
            "rule-id": "3",
            "rule-name": "include tables - schema c",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "c%",
                "table-name": "%"
            },
            "rule-action": "include",
            "filters": []
        }
       
    ]
}

